# React native image component reading the local cache file is very stuck

Tags: image, react-native

In react native, when I use the `Image` component, I have a lot of images to show.

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://img.google.com/1.jpg' }} />
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://img.google.com/2.jpg' }} />
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://img.google.com/3.jpg' }} />
........
```

Very smooth

But when loading a local cache file

```
<Image source={{ uri: '/Users/Username/../1.jpg' }} />
<Image source={{ uri: '/Users/Username/../2.jpg' }} />
<Image source={{ uri: '/Users/Username/../3.jpg' }} />
........
```

The phone will become very slow, especially IOS, and even crash

Causes me no way to use the module `react-native-cached-image` and `react-native-img-cache`

I tried replacing `Image` with `react-native-fast-image`, but it was just a little better.

what should I do? help me

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView add removeClippedSubviews={true} fix it